# Reduce height on h1 with display: table-cell

Tags: html, css, cellspacing

I centered text in a table cell using display: table-cell, vertical-align: middle, and text-align: center.  However, there is annoying spacing above and below the text now.  How can I remove it completely?  I want zero margin/padding all around the text.

PS- I've tried `border collapse: collapse` and can't seem to get it to work.

(also see fiddle below...)

**HTML:**

```
  <body>
    <div>
    <h1><a href=#>H</a></h1>
    <h1><a href=#>E</a></h1>
    <h1><a href=#>L</a></h1>
    <h1><a href=#>L</a></h1>
    <h1><a href=#>O</a></h1>
    </div>
  </body>
```

**CSS:**

```
    body {
        font-family: 'Sigmar One', cursive;
        font-size: 100px;
        color: white;
        text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #000;

        background-color:blue;

        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }


    div {
        position:absolute; 
        height:100%; 
        width:100%;
        display: table;
    }

    h1 {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align:center;
    }

    a:visited, a:active {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
    }

    a:link {
        text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
        text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(255,255,255,.25);
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
           -moz-background-clip: text;
                background-clip: text;
    }

    a:hover {
        text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #000;
        color: white;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8Huu7/8/

Comment: Is the text "hello" to be displayed as a single line or as a vertical column one character wide? You typeset "hello" as a column.

Comment: @MarcAudet I plan on making each one a link.  I typset it that way for readability.  I want it all to be on one row.  Just updated it to reflect those changes.

Comment: Could one wrap the links in a wrapper element?

Comment: Sure.  I actually tweaked it so that each link is inside of a separate h1.  But it can be inside of a span/div.  Whatever makes it work. PS- I just updated the question to reflect the tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

use the inline display property like so:

```
h1 {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align:center;
        display: inline;
    }
```

Comment: Nope. That breaks my other display: table-cell.

Comment: oh, I'm sorry I didn't notice the table-cell line, why do you need it anyway?

Comment: I need the table-cell to center the text in the middle of the page horizontally.

Comment: why don't you use the width property for the table and set it to 100%?

Comment: or set a fixed width to your table and giv it a margin: 0 auto; in the css

Comment: If you are referring to my div, it is already set to display: table and width: 100%.